# What is the Runtime Complexity of this code?

Tags: algorithm

What would be the runtime complexity of this piece of code. The code works as it is supposed to work, I am just a little confused about the runtime complexity.

```
int Something(int x[]){
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    //some code over here
    i=-1;
}
```

Please be aware this is not an infinite loop since there is a continue and break statement in the loop. However it does loop quite a few times because of the condition i = -1 at the end of the loop.

O(n) complexity means that there are no nested loops and this code has no nested loops. But I don't really think this will be O(n). It also won't be O(n^2) or anything like that since there aren't any nested loops.

Comment: Are you asking about memory or time?  `O(n) complexity means that there are no nested loops and this code has no nested loops` -- it's not that simple. `It also won't be O(n^2) or anything like that since there aren't any nested loops` -- not that simple.  `there is a continue and break statement in the loop` -- how are we supposed to help if we can't even see all of the code?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the break / continue conditions. Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: What is the maximum number of times `i=-1;` is executed? When is it executed w.r.t. the last value of `i`?

Comment: That's like asking for the complexity of `while(f()) { }`, where "`f` is some function that returns some value". Ask the author of `f`, not us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In it's current form this *is* O(infinity). It might never stop.

If there is a break statement in the loop you have to provide the full code. Without that, analysis is not possible.

Comment: Read the rest of the question. It does stop.

Comment: @sch: No, it doesn't. `O()` is an upper limit. For more accuracy, `Θ()`, I agree.

Comment: @ypercube - What's the complexity of `while(true){break;}`?

Comment: @sch: that's Θ(1). but also O(infinity).

Comment: @sch: that was me.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Equals_sign "A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function." 1, n and infinity are all upper bounds for 1. if you still don't get it check the formal definition and substitute in it.

Comment: @sch: well, for his question, `O(infinity)` is the best we can state.